# PHP: push variable number of elements to associative array

Tags: php, associative-array

A folder on my server holds a variable number of images. I'm working on a PHP script that is intended to retrieve the entire list of files there (a list of filenames) and create an associative array like so:

```
$list = array(1=>"image1.png", 2=>"image2.png", ...);
```

Basically, the list vector starts as empty and when a new image is found, its name has to be added to the list, with an incremented index:  *i=>"image[i].png"*

How do I go about achieving this? Or in other words, how do I push a new element to my array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are referring to this as an associative-array, but if you want to add somethign to an array, do it like this

```
   $list = array();
   $list[] = "image1.png";
   $list[] = ....;
   $list[] = "imagei.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are in fact re-implementing [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob)?

```
$list = glob('/path/to/images/*.png');
```

If you are really want to reimplement it yourself

```
$i = 0;
$list = array();
while (file_exists('/path/to/image' . (++$i) . '.png'))
  $list[$i] = "image$i.png";
```

Comment: @Matt No, php.net has a bad day. Just push F5 for a while ;)

Comment: add www... php.net is broken today

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push new item to your array, try with:

```
$list[] = "image" + ( count($list) + 1 ) + ".png";
```

If your items' indexes starts with `1`, add `+1` in the name as described above. If you are starting from `0` as it is natural behaviour, skip it and use as described below:

```
 $list[] = "image" + count($list) + ".png";
```